# Replacing some characters in a NSString

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, windows-1252

I have this XML file encoded in `windows-1252` and I haven't found any method to get a proper `UTF-8` encoding from this file so far. It's a file containing a lot of accented characters that I need to display.

What I want to do, is to replace any encoding windows-1252 character myself. I would like to know how to do this :

```
NSString * eat = @"j'ai mangU00c8 une pomme";
```

to

```
NSString neweat = @"j'ai mangé une pomme";
```

I found many ways to replace a character which is not in a word, but I need here to replace characters (so here `U00c8`) that can be anywhere in a given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEcoding is not giving you proper result try this

```
   NSString * eat = @"j'ai mangU00c8 une pomme";

    eat = [eat stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"U00c8"
                                         withString:@"é"];
```

Comment: I tried this but not in a proper way, retried with your help and it's working fine. Thank you. Now I'll do my category...